# Peewee AttributeError - When select with more than one join

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, peewee, flask-peewee

**I needs help please**, I'm getting the following error when I try a select with join in **a existing database** *(it's from a client, and I have only permission for read (select) I can't modify it in any aspect)*

*May be the error is in the model classes, but I'm new in Peewee ORM and I don't know as well how to declarate these relationships*:::

*(work) C:\Users\eguzman\Documents\python-work\asterisk-insert-reminder>python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 41, in
row.ageagendas.CODIGO, row.ageagendas.PER_ID, row.stkpersonas.DOCUMENTO))
AttributeError: 'AgeCitas' object has no attribute 'stkpersonas'*

**The code: script.py**

```
import peewee as pw
from classes.model import MySqlDbModel, AgeCitas, AgeAgendas, StkPersonas


class SelectCitasToRemind(MySqlDbModel):

    @staticmethod
    def selectCitasToRemind():
        cit = AgeCitas.alias()
        age = AgeAgendas.alias()
        per = StkPersonas.alias()
        query = (cit.select(
            cit.CIT_ID, cit.AGE_ID, cit.FECHAHORA,
            age.AGE_ID, age.CODIGO, age.CEN_ID, age.PER_ID,
            per.PER_ID, per.DOCUMENTO, per.NOMBRE)
            .join(age, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(cit.AGE_ID == age.AGE_ID))
            .join(per, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(age.PER_ID == per.PER_ID))
            .where((cit.CIT_ID.is_null(False))
                   & (cit.PAC_ID.is_null(False))
                   )
            .limit(10)
        )
        return query


 query = SelectCitasToRemind.selectCitasToRemind()

 for row in query:
     print("{} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {}".format(
        row.CIT_ID, row.AGE_ID, row.FECHAHORA,
        row.ageagendas.CODIGO, row.ageagendas.PER_ID, row.stkpersonas.DOCUMENTO))
```

The code: **classes/model.py**

```
import peewee as pw


# Conection to mydbname database
dbn = 'mydbname'
user = 'myusername'
pwd = '******'
host = 'localhost'
prt = 3306

db = pw.MySQLDatabase(dbn, user=user,
                  password=pwd,  host=host, port=prt)


class MySqlDbModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class AgeCitas(MySqlDbModel):
    CIT_ID = pw.BigIntegerField()
    AGE_ID = pw.BigIntegerField()
    FECHAHORA = pw.DateTimeField()
    ACT_ID = pw.BigIntegerField()
    PAC_ID = pw.BigIntegerField()
    ASIGNADA = pw.CharField()
    IND_ID = pw.BigIntegerField()
    ACUDIO = pw.DoubleField()
    ORDEN = pw.DoubleField()

class Meta:
    table_name = 'AGE_CITAS'


class AgeAgendas(MySqlDbModel):
    AGE_ID = pw.DecimalField()
    CODIGO = pw.CharField()
    CEN_ID = pw.DecimalField()
    PER_ID = pw.DecimalField()
    NPR_ID = pw.DecimalField()
    DESCRIPCION = pw.CharField()
    COLOR = pw.CharField()

class Meta:
    table_name = 'AGE_AGENDAS'


class StkPersonas(MySqlDbModel):
    PER_ID = pw.BigIntegerField()
    DOCUMENTO = pw.CharField()
    NOMBRE = pw.CharField()
    APELLIDO1 = pw.CharField()
    APELLIDO2 = pw.CharField()
    FECHA_ALTA = pw.DateTimeField()
    FECHA_BAJA = pw.DateTimeField()
    EMAIL = pw.CharField()
    TELEFONO1 = pw.CharField()
    TELEFONO2 = pw.CharField()
    TELEFONO3 = pw.CharField()
    TELEFONO4 = pw.CharField()
    SEXO = pw.CharField()
    NACIMIENTO = pw.DateTimeField()
    ES_PACIENTE = pw.CharField()
    ES_PROFESIONAL = pw.CharField()

class Meta:
    table_name = 'STK_PERSONAS'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't appear to have actual foreign-keys, you'll need to tell peewee how to reconstruct the model graph by providing aliases in your join predicates:

```
       .join(age, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(cit.AGE_ID == age.AGE_ID).alias('agecitas'))
       .join(per, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(age.PER_ID == per.PER_ID).alias('sktpersona'))
```

Comment: The problem is that the database it's from a client, and I have only permission for read (select) I can't modify it in any aspect. I've make the changes above, but It's continues with the same error

Comment: Maybe it's not possible to play with joins because of database design?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If **remove** the **second join, it's work**, but **I really need help** to make it's works with both joins, however::

```
import peewee as pw
from classes.model import BaseModel, AgeCitas, AgeAgendas, StkPersonas


class SelectCitasToRemind(BaseModel):

    @staticmethod
    def selectCitasToRemind():
        cit = AgeCitas.alias()
        age = AgeAgendas.alias()
        query = (cit.select(
            cit.CIT_ID, cit.AGE_ID, cit.FECHAHORA,
            age.AGE_ID, age.CODIGO, age.CEN_ID, age.PER_ID)
            .join(age, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(cit.AGE_ID ==   age.AGE_ID).alias('agecitas'))
            .where((cit.CIT_ID.is_null(False))
                   & (cit.PAC_ID.is_null(False))
                   )
            .limit(10)
        )
        return query


 query = SelectCitasToRemind.selectCitasToRemind()

for row in query:
    print("{} | {} | {} | {} | {}".format(
        row.CIT_ID, row.AGE_ID, row.FECHAHORA,
        row.agecitas.CODIGO, row.agecitas.PER_ID))
```

**Result:**
(work) C:\Users\eguzman\Documents\python-work\asterisk-insert-reminder-temp>python script.py
744903633820 | 11540 | 2014-02-03 09:00:00 | xxxxx | 10174325
744903633837 | 11540 | 2014-02-05 08:00:00 | xxxxx | 10174325
744903634152 | 11540 | 2014-02-17 15:00:00 | xxxxx | 10174325
744903634179 | 11540 | 2014-02-20 15:10:00 | xxxxx | 10174325
744903634224 | 11540 | 2014-01-30 17:00:00 | xxxxx | 10174325
744903634491 | 11560 | 2014-02-18 14:15:00 | xxxxx | 10174353
744903634541 | 11540 | 2014-03-06 09:40:00 | xxxxx | 10174325
744903634753 | 11620 | 2014-04-10 08:30:00 | xxxxx | 11077145
744903634976 | 11640 | 2014-04-21 08:30:00 | xxxxx | 11077165
744903634979 | 11640 | 2014-04-21 09:15:00 | xxxxx | 11077165

***But I really need de second join, How I can to make it works with both joins???***

```
.join(age, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(cit.AGE_ID == age.AGE_ID).alias('agecitas'))
.join(per, pw.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(age.PER_ID == per.PER_ID).alias('sktpersona'))
```

And doing:

```
for row in query:
print("{} | {} | {} | {} | {} | {}".format(
    row.CIT_ID, row.AGE_ID, row.FECHAHORA,
    row.agecitas.CODIGO, row.agecitas.PER_ID, row.sktpersona.DOCUMENTO))
```

Thanks